# Gradle-release plugin and SSH configuration in a Gitlab CI context

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci, gradle-release-plugin

I'm using *gradle-release* plugin in a CI/CD context with GitLab-CI.

I have set up a public private key in GitLab to allow my pipeline to push stuff in the repo but I have an issue, I guess, with how to pass SSH info to gradle process.

In my pipeline script, I have a `before_script` and I do

```
- eval $(ssh-agent -s)
- bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "${MY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}")'
```

`MY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` is stored in the GitLab CI variables.

Then I set my remote url with the ssh style for git repo

```
git remote set-url origin git@${remoteUrl}
```

I checkout my branch

```
git checkout -B ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

then I call for the plugin

```
./gradlew release --info -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true
```

I have a an issue during the plugin process

```
> Failed to run [git remote update] - [Fetching origin ][Host key
> verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> 
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists. error: Could not fetch origin ]
```

Do you have an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Why can't you do just got clone and checkout the branch.  Does git fetch work via CLI? The Gradle plugin does a project exec and it might be that the ssh key is not available. I think the project exec always has a fresh env

Comment: @Hillkorn In fact I want to make an automatic release pipeline using its plugin. I don't want to use the CLI.

Comment: Did you checked why "Host key verification failed." happens? Looks like your ssh config has trouble to very the host key.

Comment: what I think cause this issue with SSH it's that the ssh config is not passed to the process running the release plugin. So I have this error. The shell has the config through ````bash -c 'ssh-add <(echo "${MY_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}")'```` but the gradlew script isn't transfering the config to all the command it runs.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  did you manage to get a solution?